# How to add multiple apps to the homescreen(s) at once?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

I have a bunch of apps installed. I don't want to add them one by one, but I need many of them directly on my homescreen(s). Is there a faster way? This is Nexus 7 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't with the stock launcher, but in [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en) you can multi-select apps in the **Add to Home screen** list and add them all at once to either the home screen or a folder. I've also read that LG Lucid's default launcher has a customization that adds this feature. There may be other launchers that can do it, but those are the only ones I know of.